# python copy_tree runs but doesn't actually copy the directory to the destination

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i'm trying to simply copy a directory to another directory on the same windows machine. This code runs without any errors but I got to the directory and it never copied it. Here is my code. Any ideas?

```
import File
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree


if __name__ == "__main__":

    sourceFolder = File.File
    targetFolder = File.File

    sourceFolder.filePath = 'C:\\Workspace\\PythonAutomation\\1-DEV\\PythonAutomation'
    targetFolder.filePath = 'C:\\Workspace\\PythonAutomation\\2-QA'


    copy_tree(sourceFolder.filePath, targetFolder.filePath)
```

**Edit:**
 note that the content in the dir is python scripts and a Visual studio Solution. Could that be the issue? Is there only certain file types that the copy_tree can copy?

Comment: ...what the heck are you doing with that `File.File` stuff? Why are you not just doing `copy_tree('C:\\Workspace\\PythonAutomation\\1-DEV\\PythonAutomation', 'C:\\Workspace\\PythonAutomation\\2-QA')`?

Comment: What is `File.File`? You're probably overwriting `File.File.filePath`, so `sourceFolder.filePath` and `targetFolder.filePath` are identical. Don't be clever. Just use strings.

Comment: its an object I created for other projects. It doesn't make sense in this example but it does in other parts. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: And why are you pulling this function out of `distutils.dir_util`? Are you sure you don't want [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)?

Comment: can you explain the difference? @user2357112

Comment: @Pintang I can't imagine it making sense to use a single object (uninstantiated class?) for two things.

Comment: @Nick T this object is used in over 10 python projects I've created. I guess its habit now to just create it. In this instance you are correct. it makes no sense lol.

Comment: `distutils` is a tool for distributing Python modules. You don't seem to be doing that, and direct use of `distutils` is no longer recommended even for its designed use case. `shutil` is a collection of general-purpose operations on files and collections of files, and `shutil.copytree` is the usual tool for a recursive directory copy in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's basically what's going on. Because you gave a single, mutable object (I'm guessing it's a class definition, but it doesn't have to be) multiple names, changing it via one name changes it via all names.

```
class File:
    class File:
        pass

spam = File.File
eggs = File.File

# spam and eggs refer to the *exact same thing*
assert spam is eggs

# we can lazily create a "cheese" attribute inside it
spam.cheese = 'leicester'
# but because spam and eggs are identical, this overwrites it
eggs.cheese = 'stilton'

assert spam.cheese == eggs.cheese
assert spam.cheese is eggs.cheese
```

This is functionally identical to the simple case:

```
spam = {'a': 1}
eggs = spam
eggs['a'] = 2
assert spam['a'] != 2 # fails
```

Comment: you are the bomb. Sorry if I look like a noob, I completely spaced that logic error. Creating the objects correctly ex: File.File(attributes and stuff) fixed the error also switching to shutil.copytree. thanks everyone!